# With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I installed Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition but when i connect to the Instance i see message
"With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options".

How can i find that these options are not enabled on my system.

sqlplus / as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

Answer (score 0):

Oracle installs many extra-price options by default. You don't need to uninstall them - as long as you don't use them you won't have to pay for them. Feature usage is tracked in `DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS`.

For example, to find out if you're actually using partitioning, and need a license, use this query:

```
select *
from dba_feature_usage_statistics
where lower(name) like '%partition%';
```

There are at least two results, one for "Partitioning (system)" and one for "Partitioning (user)". Some Oracle options internally use partitioning, but those system uses don't count against you.